# Draw into PDF File

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I'm new with Apples PDF Kit but what I'm trying to achieve is that the user can sign a form, given as a PDF. I have a ViewController where I can write some text in my pdf but as soon as I add it from the imageView to the pdf as an annotation, its getting moved and scaled.. I guess this is the important part of the code:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let signatureImage = tempImageView.image, let page = pdfView.currentPage else { return }
        let pageBounds = page.bounds(for: .cropBox)
        let imageStamp = ImageStampAnnotation(with: signatureImage, forBounds: pageBounds, withProperties: nil)
        page.addAnnotation(imageStamp)

        tempImageView.image = nil
    }
```

The class I created to add a Image as a PDFAnnotation:

```
class ImageStampAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {

    var image: UIImage!

    init(with image: UIImage!, forBounds bounds: CGRect, withProperties properties: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.stamp, withProperties: properties)
        self.image = image
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        guard let cgImage = self.image.cgImage else { return }
        context.draw(cgImage, in: self.bounds)
    }
}
```

The tempImageView is an imageview, laying upon a PDFView. The imageView shows the text where I draw it with my fingers but as soon as I release my finger, it's moved and rescaled..